# Issue regarding fetching only those records where field value contains only one occurrence of a particular character in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I need to write a rails active record where clause where I have to fetch those rows where name (name is a column in my table) contains only one occurrence of the character '.'

For example, if there is two rows in the table where name is "a.b" and "a.b.c", then my query should return the row having name "a.b" only.

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can for example remove the dots and compare length.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (char_length(name) - char_length(replace(name, '.', '')))=1
```

This is not very efficient though, because indexes can't be utilized.
To make things smoother, you could store the number of dots (depth?) in its own column with an index and query based on that. This could be done in insert/update trigger or in application layer, whatever suits your situation.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=789ba34076602741b79a1c448ff06de3)

Answer (score 1):

with regexp ? you can try this :

```
select * from "table" where "name" ~ '^[^\.]*\.[^\.]*$'
```